# ConfigMap also for kubernetes configurations?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 kubernetes descriptor files (yml): one for prod and one for test.
The only difference between them is the fact that in production I want up to 4 replicas to grant horizontal scaling, while in test I'm fine.
So the production yaml has the following more:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: prodAutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: 4
 minReplicas: 1
 scaleTargetRef:
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
name: myapp
 targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

If it was possible to put this configuration inside a config map I could have two identical descriptors and avoid maintaining both.
Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that allows you only to maintain one configuration for both environmental?

Comment: Yes, in this case there is only one small difference so it would make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incredibly straight-forward (6 lines total) to do this with [`ytt`](https://get-ytt.io)

`./config/autoscaler.yml`

```yaml
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: prodAutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: #@ data.values.replicas
 minReplicas: 1
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   name: myapp
   targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

`./config/values.yml`

```
#@data/values
replicas: 1
```

`./prod/values.yml`

```
#@data/values
replicas: 4
```

To deploy to test:

```
$ ytt -f config/
```

To deploy to prod:

```
$ ytt -f config/ -f prod/
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize) it might be overkill just for one file, but later when a number of files increase it will be helpful.

1. kustomize

`$ kubectl kustomize dev/`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: dev-AutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: 1
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myapp
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

`$ kubectl kustomize prod/`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: prod-AutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: 4
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myapp
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

```
.
├── base
│   ├── HorizontalPodAutoscaler.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── dev
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── map.yaml
└── prod
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── map.yaml
```

`$cat base/HorizontalPodAutoscaler.yaml`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: AutoScaling
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myapp
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  maxReplicas: 0
  minReplicas: 1
```

`$cat base/kustomization.yaml`

```
resources:
- HorizontalPodAutoscaler.yaml
`$cat dev/kustomization.yaml`
bases:
- ../base
namePrefix: dev-
patchesStrategicMerge:
- map.yaml
```

`$ cat dev/map.yaml`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: AutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: 1
```

`$ cat prod/kustomization.yaml`

```
bases:
- ../base
namePrefix: prod-
patchesStrategicMerge:
- map.yaml
```

`$ cat prod/map.yaml`

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: AutoScaling
spec:
  maxReplicas: 4
```

2. ytt

You can also use [ytt](https://get-ytt.io/) for templating.